# How to resizing an Icon / Icon Button in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, icons, flutter-layout

I have 2 questions.

1. how to scale our icon ? I mean not a default icon from Flutter. but when you change into an Image. I have an Icon Button with an image like this:

```
Row(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          IconButton(
                            icon: new Image.asset("images/IG.png"),
                          ),
                          IconButton(
                            icon: new Image.asset("images/Twitter.png"),
                          ),
                          IconButton(
                            icon: new Image.asset("images/Fb.png"),
                          ),
                        ],
                      )
```

its only 3 icons. when I add more icon, its gonna break the layout into bricks yellow-black. how to make them become smaller ?

[image]

2. Question above is for IconButton.
   how to change an Icon with an Image ?
   here are the code:

   `Icon(Icons.star, color: Colors.red)`

how to change the '`star`' with Image.asset ?
without any referal to other link, that only show the icon.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can use `size` property for `Icon`.

```
Icon(
  Icons.radio_button_checked,
  size: 12,
),
```

And for `IconButton` you can use

```
Transform.scale(
  scale: 0.5,
  child: IconButton(
    onPressed: (){},
    icon: new Image.asset("images/IG.png"),
  ),
),
```

Comment: So I use scale for resizing those icon ?
well let me try but thank you so much for your answer :) @CopsOnRoad

Comment: For normal `Icon` you can use `size` but for IconButton with your own images you should use `scale`. Please take your time and do let me know if that helped. Thanks :)

Comment: yes. if normal Icon I can use "SIZE" but I stuck at ICON BUTTON case. this is the first time I know about "SCALE" for icon button. thank you for you answer. really help me. :)

Answer (score 2):

Below code set width & height for the `IconButton` and make it to the center of your Container.

```
 Container(
            height: 18.0,
            width: 18.0,
            color: Colors.yellow,
            child: new IconButton(
              padding: new EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
              color: Colors.red,
              icon: new Icon(Icons.clear, size: 18.0),
              onPressed: null,
            )
        )
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For first question u can use sized box to contain IconButton and if it is breaking when adding more either use scroll or reduce width and height of sized box with respect to child.

```
new SizedBox(
   height: /*calculate from width and no:of child*/,
   width: /*calculate from width and no:of child*/,
   child: new IconButton(
      padding: new EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
      icon: new Image.asset("images/IG.png"),
      onPressed: null,
   )
)
```

for second question u can use `AssetImage('icons/heart.png', package: 'my_icons')`
you can refer [Doc](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images)

Comment: well I appreciate your answer for helping me find the solutions.
but like CopsOnRoad said your code wont work for IconButton.
I already try it.

but once again thank you so much, 

@Vineeth Mohan

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer my questions based on All Suhu answers here and based on my experience asking uncle google.

1. how to scale our icon ? I mean not a default icon from Flutter. but when you change into an Image. ?

mr @CopsOnRoad has give his answer on the comment column. and it really works. thanks :)
my answer:

```
Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Image.asset("images/line.png", width: 30,),
                          SizedBox(width: 5,),
                          Image.asset("images/Wa.png", width: 30,),
                          SizedBox(width: 5,),
                          Image.asset("images/IG.png", width: 30,),
                          SizedBox(width: 5,),
                          Image.asset("images/Twitter.png", width: 30,),
                          SizedBox(width: 5,),
                          Image.asset("images/Fb.png", width: 30,),

                        ],
```

I use an image asset and give them a size to resize.
but this is only dumb way. the great way you can see mr. Cops answer above.

2. how to change an Icon with an Image ? here are the code:
   `Icon(Icons.star, color: Colors.red)`

my answer is by using ImageIcon. Its makes an image just like an icon. here the code.

```
  ImageIcon(AssetImage("images/Free Ongkir.png")),
```

because I still cant change the "star" into an image asset then I used ImageIcon.
you can change the size also. by adding "size" behind the first ")".

hope this could help you :)