# Show icons bigger [Flutter]

Tags: flutter

I would like show an icon bigger without increasing the total size of a widget maybe by only showing a section of the icon.

[image: How it should look like]

How can I do this?

Comment: Please post the code which you tried so far for it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resizing an Icon / Icon Button in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55571536/how-to-resizing-an-icon-icon-button-in-flutter)

Comment: @Mobina yes. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An answer in [How to resizing an Icon / Icon Button in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55571536/how-to-resizing-an-icon-icon-button-in-flutter)
helped me.

I have used `Transform.scale` to scale it.

```
return FittedBox(
  child: FlatButton(
    color: Colors.red,
    onPressed: () {},
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(45),
    ),
    child: Row(
      children: [
        Transform.scale(
          child: Icon(LetsGoIcons.fighting, color: Colors.white),
          scale: 2,
        ),
        SizedBox(width: 10),
        Text("Fighting",
            style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: Colors.white,
                letterSpacing: 0.7,
                fontSize: 18))
      ],
    ),
  )
);
```

[This is how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yecZ3.png)

Answer (score 0):

Simply set the size property to increase the size

`Icon(Icons.clear, size: 18.0)`